# Matrix template, memory leak

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, valgrind

I code a simple program to apply a complex function (z,exp(z),...) to a pgm image and return the result. The program is working and does what it should do. However, there are 11 memory leaks that I'm not been able to work out. My guess is that the trouble is in the matrix template container I code and its constructors and destructor.
To debug I'm using valgrind and the program has been written in c++.

The result of running valgrind is the following:

```
==7690== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7690== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7690== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7690== Command: ./tp0 -i f14.pgm -f z -o ff14.pgm
==7690== 
==7690== 
==7690== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7690==     in use at exit: 160 bytes in 11 blocks
==7690==   total heap usage: 45 allocs, 34 frees, 18,357 bytes allocated
==7690== 
==7690== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C298A0: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:389)
==7690==    by 0x404871: Matrix<Pixel>::Matrix(unsigned int, unsigned int) (matrix.hpp:44)
==7690==    by 0x404471: PGMImage::PGMImage(unsigned int, unsigned int) (pgm_image.cpp:14)
==7690==    by 0x405475: PGMParser::set_pgm_dimensions(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) (pgm_parser.cpp:147)
==7690==    by 0x4050CD: PGMParser::get_pgm() (pgm_parser.cpp:94)
==7690==    by 0x404D67: PGMParser::PGMParser(std::string const&) (pgm_parser.cpp:25)
==7690==    by 0x404212: main (main.cpp:52)
==7690== 
==7690== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C298A0: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:389)
==7690==    by 0x403703: Matrix<Complex>::Matrix(unsigned int, unsigned int) (matrix.hpp:44)
==7690==    by 0x4024A5: PGMTransformation::PGMTransformation(PGMImage const&, std::string const&) (PGMTransformation.cpp:49)
==7690==    by 0x404240: main (main.cpp:55)
==7690== 
==7690== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C298A0: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:389)
==7690==    by 0x4049C9: Matrix<Pixel>::Matrix(Matrix<Pixel> const&) (matrix.hpp:56)
==7690==    by 0x404579: PGMImage::PGMImage(PGMImage const&) (pgm_image.cpp:31)
==7690==    by 0x4024DD: PGMTransformation::PGMTransformation(PGMImage const&, std::string const&) (PGMTransformation.cpp:57)
==7690==    by 0x404240: main (main.cpp:55)
==7690== 
==7690== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C298A0: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:389)
==7690==    by 0x4048B4: Matrix<Pixel>::Matrix(unsigned int, unsigned int) (matrix.hpp:46)
==7690==    by 0x404471: PGMImage::PGMImage(unsigned int, unsigned int) (pgm_image.cpp:14)
==7690==    by 0x405475: PGMParser::set_pgm_dimensions(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) (pgm_parser.cpp:147)
==7690==    by 0x4050CD: PGMParser::get_pgm() (pgm_parser.cpp:94)
==7690==    by 0x404D67: PGMParser::PGMParser(std::string const&) (pgm_parser.cpp:25)
==7690==    by 0x404212: main (main.cpp:52)
==7690== 
==7690== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C298A0: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:389)
==7690==    by 0x404A15: Matrix<Pixel>::Matrix(Matrix<Pixel> const&) (matrix.hpp:59)
==7690==    by 0x404579: PGMImage::PGMImage(PGMImage const&) (pgm_image.cpp:31)
==7690==    by 0x4024DD: PGMTransformation::PGMTransformation(PGMImage const&, std::string const&) (PGMTransformation.cpp:57)
==7690==    by 0x404240: main (main.cpp:55)
==7690== 
==7690== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C29180: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:324)
==7690==    by 0x40445E: PGMImage::PGMImage(unsigned int, unsigned int) (pgm_image.cpp:14)
==7690==    by 0x405475: PGMParser::set_pgm_dimensions(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) (pgm_parser.cpp:147)
==7690==    by 0x4050CD: PGMParser::get_pgm() (pgm_parser.cpp:94)
==7690==    by 0x404D67: PGMParser::PGMParser(std::string const&) (pgm_parser.cpp:25)
==7690==    by 0x404212: main (main.cpp:52)
==7690== 
==7690== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C29180: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:324)
==7690==    by 0x40248A: PGMTransformation::PGMTransformation(PGMImage const&, std::string const&) (PGMTransformation.cpp:49)
==7690==    by 0x404240: main (main.cpp:55)
==7690== 
==7690== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 8 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C298A0: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:389)
==7690==    by 0x403740: Matrix<Complex>::Matrix(unsigned int, unsigned int) (matrix.hpp:46)
==7690==    by 0x4024A5: PGMTransformation::PGMTransformation(PGMImage const&, std::string const&) (PGMTransformation.cpp:49)
==7690==    by 0x404240: main (main.cpp:55)
==7690== 
==7690== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 9 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C29180: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:324)
==7690==    by 0x404564: PGMImage::PGMImage(PGMImage const&) (pgm_image.cpp:31)
==7690==    by 0x4024DD: PGMTransformation::PGMTransformation(PGMImage const&, std::string const&) (PGMTransformation.cpp:57)
==7690==    by 0x404240: main (main.cpp:55)
==7690== 
==7690== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 10 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C29180: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:324)
==7690==    by 0x405464: PGMParser::set_pgm_dimensions(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) (pgm_parser.cpp:147)
==7690==    by 0x4050CD: PGMParser::get_pgm() (pgm_parser.cpp:94)
==7690==    by 0x404D67: PGMParser::PGMParser(std::string const&) (pgm_parser.cpp:25)
==7690==    by 0x404212: main (main.cpp:52)
==7690== 
==7690== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 11 of 11
==7690==    at 0x4C29180: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:324)
==7690==    by 0x4024CB: PGMTransformation::PGMTransformation(PGMImage const&, std::string const&) (PGMTransformation.cpp:57)
==7690==    by 0x404240: main (main.cpp:55)
==7690== 
==7690== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7690==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7690==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7690==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7690==    still reachable: 160 bytes in 11 blocks
==7690==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7690== 
==7690== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7690== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The part of code I think is crashing of matrix template is the following:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
    private:
        T** matrix_;
        unsigned int rows_;
        unsigned int cols_;

    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(unsigned int, unsigned int);
        Matrix(Matrix const &);
        ~Matrix();
        Matrix const &operator=(Matrix const &);

//more methods...
};

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix()
: matrix_(0), rows_(0), cols_(0) {}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols)
{
    matrix_ = new T*[rows];
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows; i++)
        matrix_[i] = new T[cols];
    rows_ = rows;
    cols_ = cols;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix<T> const & m_orig)
{
    rows_ = m_orig.rows_;
    cols_ = m_orig.cols_;
    matrix_ = new T*[rows_];
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows_; i++)
    {
        matrix_[i] = new T[cols_];
        for(unsigned int j=0; j < cols_; j++)
            matrix_[i][j]=m_orig.matrix_[i][j];
    }
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix()
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows_; i++)
        delete matrix_[i];
    delete []matrix_;
    rows_ = 0;
    cols_ = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> const & Matrix<T>::operator=(Matrix const & m_orig)
{
    if(this != &m_orig)
    {
            for(unsigned int k=0; k < rows_; k++)
                delete matrix_[k];
            delete matrix_;
        rows_ = m_orig.rows_;
        cols_ = m_orig.cols_;
        matrix_ = new T*[rows_];
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows_; i++)
        {
            matrix_[i] = new T[cols_];
            for(unsigned int j=0; j < cols_; j++)
                matrix_[i][j]=m_orig.matrix_[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

There are other classes that could fail, but valgrind tracks almost every leak to the matrix container.
Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at that destructor again, especially the `delete` statement in the loop. As you use `new[]` to allocate, you need to use `delete[]` to free.

Comment: Use `vector<vector<T>>` and you won't leak memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk but that will be terrible on reallocations and indirections. A manually-indexed `std::vector<T>` would be the best choice.

Comment: @Quentin It will be no worse than manually managed arrays of arrays.

Comment: @NeilKirk I read his code too fast. Indeed, a double `vector` would not be worse, but still.

Comment: The answers provided are correct - but as a comment, you probably want to do `matrix_ = new T[rows][cols]` rather than what you have. It'll put your entire matrix in a contiguous block, which may or may not be true otherwise, so performance will be better.

Comment: Barry, so you think i should replace the 'for' with the just one 'new'?

Comment: `matrix_ = new T[rows][cols]` is not working. I don't know realy why. the error g++ is throwing is this: `matrix.hpp:50:10: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array [-Wvla]
  matrix_ = new T[rows][cols];
          ^
matrix.hpp:50:10: error: array size in new-expression must be constant
matrix.hpp:50:10: error: ‘cols’ is not a constant expression`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should follow the same "pattern" for *deallocation* with `delete` as you do for *allocation* with `new`,

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows_; i++)
        delete [] matrix_[i];
            // ~~   notice []
delete []matrix_;
```

Comment: Good answer. Leaks reduce to 136 instead of 160. but now i'm getting _possibly lost bytes_. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your assignment operator is not exception-safe and fails to use the correct version of `delete`: it releases the memory using `delete matrix_` rather than `delete[] matrix_`. Given the current implementation you are **much** better off replacing it by this version:

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T> const& Matrix<T>::operator= (Matrix<T> orig) {
    this->swap(orig);
    return *this;
}
template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::swap(Matrix<T>& other) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(this->matrix_, other.matrix_);
}
```

Aside from fixing the memory issues noted above, it also makes the implementation strong exception safe. Of course, doing so assumes that the copy constructor, destructor, and `swap()` are correctly implemented as they are leveraged to implement this assignment operator:

1. A copy of the original is made to create the argument (which may be elided: since a copy is made anyway taking the argument by value rather than be `const&` can reduce the number of copies).
2. The argument the left hand side are exchanged, making the left hand side the same as the original argument while the argument now contain the original left hand side state ready to be released.
3. The argument is destroyed, releasing the original left hand side state.

The destructor is also incorrect: it uses `delete matrix_[k]` instead of `delete[] matrix_[k]`. Conventionally objects are destroyed in the opposite order of construction while your code destroys objects in the opposite order. I'd recommend using `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` to maintain the data inside the `Matrix<T>`, too.

Comment: +1.  Also needs to be mentioned that the copy constructor and destructor must work correctly before using copy/swap.

Comment: right! I've changed the code as you said but the leaks are still there. I'm not sure if I'm using right the operator new and delete. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @tul1 DietmarK forgot the other two members that need to be swapped, namely `rows_` and `cols_`.  Just add those lines to his `swap` function, and you should be ok.

Comment: Nice! With all the help I think the matrix code is working and doesn't leak anymore.